# How does "to_string" work in array of string?

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, substring

I want to combine the first 4 characters of each line in txt file and compare it with the keyword I have, but
when I combine the characters, I get the sum of these 4 characters' ascii numbers(whatever).
How can I solve this problem. My code is here:
When I debuged, I saw the string search(variable) was 321.

```cpp
int main() {
    ifstream file("sentence.txt");
    
    if (file.is_open()) {
        string line;
        while (getline(file, line)) {
            string search = to_string(line[0] + line[1] + line[2]); // you see what I mean
            if ("dog" == search) {
                cout << "there is dog";
            }
            else {
                cout << "there is no dog"<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @yakubalkis This string search = to_string(line[0] + line[1] + line[2]); does not make a sense.

Comment: `line[0] + line[1] + line[2]` is going to result in an `int` with some value and it is that value that is being converted to a string.

Comment: @yakubalkis And I do not see here to_string(line[0] + line[1] + line[2]); 4 characters. I have counted only 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`line[0]`, `line[1]`, and `line[2]` are `char`s, not `std::string`s.  `char` is an integer type, so adding two `char`s together results in a single integer that is the sum of the two operands.  It does not produce a `std::string` that is the concatenation of the two `char`s.

To get a substring of a `std::string` use the `substr` member function:

```
std::string search = line.substr(0, 3);
```

Or, if you actually need to construct a `std::string` from individual `char`s, use the constructor that accepts a `std::initializer_list<char>`:

```
std::string search{line[0], line[1], line[2]};
```

Answer (score 5):

The function `std::to_string()` is designed to convert a number into a string representation. It is not what you need.

There is no need to create the new string `search` to check whether the string `line` starts with the string `"dog"`.

Creating the new string `search` is inefficient.

Instead, you could write for example

```
if ( line.compare( 0, 3, "dog" ) == 0 ) {
    cout << "there is dog";
}
else {
    cout << "there is no dog" << endl;
}
```

Or, if your compiler supports C++20, you can also write:

```
if ( line.starts_with( "dog" ) ) {
    cout << "there is dog";
}
else {
    cout << "there is no dog" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been bristling at all the suggestions to use `substr`; it's far too heavyweight for something as straightforward as this. +1.

Answer (score 1):

A string made from the first characters of `line` can be obtained via `std::substr`. In this case I'd actually prefer the constructor that takes two iterators:

```
std::string first3chars{line.begin(),line.begin()+3};
```

Take care of `line`s that are less than 3 characters.

Your code adds the values of three `char`s. Adding `char`s via `+` does not concatenate them, and if it would why call `std::to_string` on the result? `char` is an integer type and what you see as 321 is the result of adding the number representations of the first 3 characters in `line`.

Comment: "*In this case I'd actually prefer the constructor that takes two iterators*" - I would have gone with the constructor that takes a `const char*` and a length: `std::string first3chars(line.c_str(), 3);`

Answer (score 1):

Is there a way for you to cast those chars (which appear to be integer type for some reason) into char type once again. Perhaps that ought to resolve the issue in case the "to_string" concatenates those 3 inputs into one; additionally intelli-sense should do the trick of explaining parameter usage and returning value.

Comment: Those chars are of type `char`. Their **sum** has type `int` because that's how arithmetic works: objects of types that are smaller than `int` are promoted to `int` (or `unsigned int`, don't worry about that for the moment).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this code is that when you access an element of a string you get a character which is an ASCII number, when you try to sum two characters you are adding their ASCII codes.

In your specific case, as you want sequential characters, the best solution would probably be to use the `substr` function ([documentation](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)) for strings. Otherwise, you would probably need to convert one of the characters to a string and then “add” the other characters to it.